# How can I use server's inbuilt windows performance monitor results in jmeter installed on local machine?

Tags: jmeter

I need to analyse the performance reports of my server for which I am using Server Performance Monitoring in Jmeter which needs an installation of Perfmon metrics collector and Perfmon Server Agent. But, as I have installed Jmeter on local and I do not have the rights to install anything on Server, I am not able to install Perfmon Server agent to get the reports. However, I came to know that a Windows server has an inbuilt Perfmon installed but I do not know how to use it.

Hence, I need help in sending the reports from server using Windows performance monitor and collecting those reports in Jmeter installed on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. In Windows Performance Monitor there is an option to connect to remote machine:

   [image: Windows Perfmon another machine]
2. You can create your own [Data Collector Set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722312(v=ws.11).aspx) and write counters data into a file. Once your test is finished you will be able to copy the file and analyze the collected metrics.

---

Unfortunately you won't be able to integrate Windows Performance Monitor reports into a JMeter test, it will be a standalone monitoring option. Basically Server Agent doesn't require "installation", you can just copy it over and make sure JMeter can connect to port 4444, see [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for details.